# Correr más de un servidor con http-server (paquete npm)

Tags: nodejs, npm

Estoy corriendo un servidor utilizando http-server y hasta hay todo bien, pero quiero correr mas servidores y me sale este error:

```
events.js:154
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at net.js:1376:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:380:13)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:933:3
```

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que por defecto http-server asigna el puerto 8080, asi que si ya existe un proceso en este puerto y vuelves a correr http-server en la consola pues arrojara error.

Debes especificar un puerto diferente cada vez que quieras correr un nuevo servidor, así:

```
http-server -p 8081
http-server -p 8082
http-server -p 8083
```

o con el puerto que quieras.